# HashiCorp Vault Is it possible to create a custom token and use this token to store a secret via Cubbyhole Response Wrapping?

Tags: hashicorp-vault, vault

i want to create a Cubbyhole Response Wrapping token outside of Vault and use this token in Vault to store a secret via Cubbyhole Response Wrapping.
https://developer.hashicorp.com/vault/docs/concepts/response-wrapping
**Is this possible?**

Offsite Notes:

Why i want to do this:
Because i cant send the token back to the customer, because i dont have a connection to the customer in that place and i dont have any chance to communicate to the customer.
The only contact is at the outside and the only chance is to create a token outside and send it to the machine which communicates to Vault.
A communication back is not given and not allowed.

I tried to generate a Cubbyhole Response Wrapping token on the Vault Website via the Website CLI and use this token on my local environment to store a secret in my local Cubbyhole via Response Wrapping.
"I wanted to test the following: If i create a wrapping token outside in a Vault and use this token in another Vault thats a usecase i could provide."
--> Unfortunally that failed.

I googled but didnt find any matching things.

If you have any idea please let me know!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.